# how to split string into NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, string, split, nsmutablearray

I want to split string into NSMutableArray

I know

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

is available but this one is for `NSArray` not for `NSMutableArray`.

I need because after spliting i want to remove element from array by using

```
-(void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

which is not possible with NSArray.

Thank you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can also just get a mutable copy of the returned array:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"..."] mutableCopy];
```

Also, remember that copy, like alloc, does allocate new memory. So when used in non-ARC code you must `autorelease` the copied array or manually `release` it when you are done with it.

Comment: The problem I have with this approach, is that it introduces a memory leak in the hands of an unexperienced developer. This seems especially risky when handling arrays (which retain their elements). Add an `autorelease` and all is well.

Answer (score 9):

Make a new `NSMutableArray` using

```
NSArray *array = [NSString componentsSeparatedByString:@"..."];
NSMutableArray *mutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

Comment: this is also right but I am split string in to array then into string and again 2-3 times till i get perfect Array...anyways thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Create a NSMutableArray from the output NSArray created by componentsSeparatedByString.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];
```